# using variables inside db column

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database

On some online resource I've come on some situation where variables (I guess) is used inside db column, so I need clarification or some online resource where I can clarify this.

Inside mssql server there is table where one column of type nvarchar has following content

```
Hello {FullName}<br /><br/>. Your username is {Username}.
```

Why this is `{FullName}` is used here (inside db), I guess that this is some kind of template where this partials should be populated from code, can someone put simple sql example of how this can be done, or real world usage explanation as simple as possible.

Comment: Well, the real world usage is templating as you guessed, in this case an activation mail for some website or application. It's not really clear to me what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These curly brackets are probably not "variables" but kind of place holders to be replaced with real life data...

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @Template VARCHAR(MAX)='Hello {FullName}<br /><br/>. Your username is {Username}';

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@Template,'{FullName}','Thomas Anderson'),'{Username}','Tom');
```

Result

```
Hello Thomas Anderson<br /><br/>. Your username is Tom
```